# How can I remove footer from RTF file in plain java or using iText RTF

Tags: java, itext, rtf

I want to read a RTF file and remove the date which is in the footer of page. I want to do this using Java only or any library like iText RTF. My file may contain some images also and I don't want to change anything in that.